# Select2 does not show the set value

Tags: jquery-select2-4, jquery-select2

There is a `select2` element :

```
<select name="commande_id" id="commande">
    <option value=""> -- Choisir une commande -- </option>
    <option value="1">COM-2-2015</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function() {
        ...
        $("#commande").select2({width:'100%'});
        ...
});
```

When I enter the page in update mode then I set the option value of the select element programmatically to be the value from database :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       ...
       <?php
        if (isset($data)) { ?>
            ...
            $("#commande").val("<?php echo $data[0]['commande_id'];?>");
            ...
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        ...
});
```

The problem is that at runtime the select element does not show the appropriate text :

[image]

But when I click it then the appropriate value is selected :

[image]

So how to make the appropriate text shown ?

Comment: I don't know if I understand it in the right way, do you want to put the right value in the right place? Isn't it better set the value and the name of the options with php ?

Comment: Check if the answer helps you in something

Comment: You need to trigger the `change` event after changing the value, that's causing the issue.

Comment: @KevinBrown please make it as answer cause it works perfectly ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are getting the `$data`, but I guess it's something like that, just an example:

```
<?php

$data[] = ["commande_id" => "1", "name_field" => "COM-2-2015"];

foreach ($data as $key => $value){
?>
<select>
    <option value='<?php echo $value['commande_id']?>'><?php echo $value['name_field'] ?></option>
</select>
<?php } ?>
```

Look it here: https://ideone.com/PSpKmu